# Using double joins

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have this code here :

```
Dim sql, sqlD, sqlE, sqlA As String
Dim rsA As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsA = New ADODB.Recordset

sqlA = "SELECT * From A INNER JOIN (SELECT B.Role From B LEFT JOIN C ON 
(B.Role=C.Role) WHERE (C.Role IS NULL and mid(B.Role,1,2)='ZE' and 
mid(B.Role,6,1)='_')) ON (A.Role=B.Role)"

rsA.Open sqlA, conn, adOpenStatic
```

So, my input data consist of 3 tables :
B table : contains all the roles
A and C tables : both the tables have further information of the roles in B table

What my code does is, the inner select pulls the value which are there in B table minus C table, and then whatever is left in B table, it does inner join with the A table.

But i am receiving error as :

> Syntax error in JOIN operation.

Please help

Comment: you need to give the 2nd table an alias name and join it on that name. Inner Join (SELECT...............) as someName ON someName .Role = A.Role

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Thanx @isaace : it works

Comment: You are welcome!